# Insertion of record in table slow in oracle 11g

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, weblogic-10.x

We have very old java application from thirdparty which insert some records in table with autocommit on(I know its bad technique but i dont have control on source).

It was working fine on Oracle 10G with acceptable delay in insertions.

Now as we migrate to Oracle 11G we observed that it take 15 Minutes for insertion of 28K records.

Please suggest any techniques to improve performance with autocommit on?

I would also like to know what type of changes are in 11G due to which its slower then 10 g in this regard?

I discussed with my DBA they are exploring some options with regard to LGWR.

Comment: Presume that you are using the correct jdbc jar when you migrate from Oracle 10g to 11g.

Comment: My application is deployed on Oracle WebLogic 10G and using DataSources. Do i need to select library ?

Comment: I am using application server datasource and from configuration files it support 11. <Driver 
    Database="Oracle" 
    Vendor="Oracle" 
    Type="Thin" 
    DatabaseVersion="10,11" 
    ForXA="false"
    Cert="true"
    ClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
  </Driver>